# Problem migrating PostGIS

Tags: migration, postgresql-9.3, postgis, postgresql-10

I need to migrate Postgres 9.3 + PostGIS 2.1 to Postgres 10.
I'm using CentOS 7.X

Using pg_upgrade it should be quite straightforward, but the problem is PostGIS.
Postgres 9.3 has PostGIS 2.1 available, whereas Postgres 10 has PostGis 2.4.4.
So I compiled PostGIS 2.4 for Postgres 9.3 and installed it.
Then for each database, I've made:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

In this way, I've migrated to PostGIS 2.4.

But when I run `pg_upgrade`, I receive this error:

> Cannot access the file «$libdir/postgis-2.1»: It doesn't exist the file or the directory.

If I do this:

```
cd /usr/pgsql-10/lib/
ln -s postgis-2.4.so postgis-2.1.so
```

It doesn't work either, because if I run `pg_ugrade` another time:

> ```
> pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.geomfromewkb("bytea")"
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 547; 1255 90291 FUNCTION geomfromewkb("bytea") ema
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not find function "LWGEOMFromWKB" in file "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-2.1.so"<br>
>     Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "public"."geomfromewkb"("bytea") RETURNS "public"."geometry"
>      LANGUAGE "c" IMMUTABLE STRICT
>      AS '$libdir/postgis-2.1', 'LWGEOMFromWKB';
> ```

Why does Postgres 9.3 reference PostGIS 2.1 after migrating to 2.4?

The other option I see is to compile PosGIS 2.1 for Postgres 10.

**UPDATE 1**

After reading [this tip](https://postgis.net/2017/06/05/postgis-backend-is-already-set/), I've done for each database I've done:

`psql mydb -c 'ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;'
psql mydb -c 'ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE;'
psql mydb -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/uninstall_legacy.sql
psql mydb -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.4/legacy.sql`

with identical results.

`SELECT probin, COUNT(*) 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE probin LIKE '%/postgis%'
GROUP BY probin
ORDER BY probin;`

returns:

```
       probin        | count 
---------------------+-------
 $libdir/postgis-2.1 |   373
```

**UPDATE 2**

This [guide](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/08/postgis-upgrade.html) explains the internals of PostGIS migration.

Clearly, PostGIS tells it migrates the extension, but doesn't apply the migration script to change the procedures.

Comment: I generally use `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO VERSION '2.4.1'` but I'm a bit surprised that applying the 2.4 legacy script doesn't cause the number of functions using the 2.4 library to be non-zero. Something is odd with your setup methinks.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you did. What do you mean that you forgot to migrate a template database?

Comment: Here is more information about template databases: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I forgot to migrate a template database.
Thereafter `pg_upgrade` upgrades successfully.